# socket::accept continual to return EGAIN

Tags: linux, sockets

I use nonblocking socket to receive new connection. But the code repeatedly fails to `accept()`.

```
int sockfd = ::socket(family, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_TCP);
::bind(sockfd, bind_addr, static_cast<socklen_t>(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)));
ret = ::listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN);

while (True) {
    ::poll(&*pollfds_.begin(), pollfds_.size(), timeoutMs);
    struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
    bzero(&addr, sizeof addr);
    socklen_t addrlen = static_cast<socklen_t>(sizeof *addr);
    int connfd = ::accept4(sockfd, sockaddr_cast(addr),
                         &addrlen, SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC);
}
```

`errno` is `EAGAIN`.

Comment: You define `connfd` twice, could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you use ipv6 (`sockaddr_in6`) or ipv4 (`::accept4`)?

Comment: @purplepsycho I copy one more line from my project.

Comment: @purplepsycho I use ipv4. sockadd_in6 is compatiable with ivp4.

Comment: Have you considered examining the result of `poll()`, or the event set, instead of blindly assuming that the socket has become readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage to `accept(2)`:

> EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
>
> The socket is marked nonblocking and no connections are present to be accepted. POSIX.1-2001 allows either error to be returned for this case, and does not require these constants to have the same value, so a portable application should check for both possibilities.

This means that the call to `accept` is made before the client has connected.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `accept`, you must call `listen` and `bind`.
**But** as your socket is not blocking, you should wait for client to wait to connect. You can do that with `select` function:

```
int sockfd = ::socket(family, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_TCP);

// addr is for accept call, sin for bind call
struct sockaddr_in6 addr, sin;
bzero(&addr, sizeof addr);

// prepare sin to tell bind to listen on any connection on given port
sin.sin6_family = family;
sin.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
sin.sin6_port = htons(port); // choose port on which client could connect
sin.sin6_scope_id = 0;

// bind socket to interface
if (::bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0)
{
    perror("bind");
}

// listen for new connection
if (::listen(sock, SOMAXCONN) < 0)
{
    perror("socket");
}

while (1)
{
    fd_set conset;
    FD_ZERO(&conset); 
    FD_SET(sockfd, &conset);

    struct timeval timeout = {10, 0};
    int maxfd = sockfd;

    // wait for new client
    select(maxfd + 1, &conset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &conset))
    {
        // a new client is waiting
        int connfd = ::accept(sockfd, &addr);
        if (connfd < 0)
        {
            perror("accept");
        }
        else
        {
            // do thing with new client
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no new client in last 10 seconds")
    }
}
```

Comment: The code before is just gist. I have paste codes of polling.